# Is it safe to do a data migration as just one operation in a larger Django migration?

Tags: python, django

I am handling what I assume is a common issue: I've realized that an existing model field of the model `Foo` would be better as a completely seperate model `Bar` with a foreign key to `Foo`. So, we need to make a schema migration. But what's more, since there is already existing data in the model field of `Foo`, we need to make a data migration before we delete that field.

So we have identified that there are three distinct steps to take:

1. Create the new table `Bar`
2. Migrate the existing data in `Foo` to the new table `Bar`
3. Delete the existing field in `Foo`

First, I make all the needed model changes in models.py, and then auto-generate a migration. Everything looks good, except we're going to lose all the data in the field, so I need to add one extra [operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations) to handle the data migration ([RunPython)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/migration-operations/#runpython). I would end up with something like the following:

```
def do_data_migration(apps, schema_editor):
    # Migrate data from Foo to Bar

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [ 
        ('exampleapp', 'migration_003'),
    ]   

    operations = [ 
        migrations.CreateModel(
            # Create the new model Bar
        ),  
        migrations.AddField(
            # Add the foreign key field to model Foo
        ),  
        migrations.RunPython(
            do_data_migration
        ),
        migrations.RemoveField(
            # Remove the old field from Foo
        ),  
    ]
```

Is it safe to run a data migration as one of several operations in a migration? My worries are that there is any sort of locking going on, or if perhaps the app registry that `RunPython` passes to `do_data_migration` won't be up to date with the preceding operations?

I am aware the I could create three migrations: one for `CreateModel` and `AddField`, the second for `RunPython`, and the last for `RemoveField`. The question is if it is functionally equivalent to do all four steps in a single migration (which provides the added benefit of making the entire migration easier to understand.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With regards to Django itself, this is perfectly safe. Each operation will receive the correct state based on all previous migrations and operations within the same migration. Your `RunPython` operation will receive an app registry that includes the new `Bar` model and still has the old field on `Foo`.

What may not be safe is the database-side of the operation. If a database supports DDL (Data Definition Language) in transactions, Django will run the complete migration in a single transaction. PostgreSQL, for example, supports DDL in transactions, but does not allow you to mix schema changes and data changes in the same transaction. Attempting to do both within a single migration/transaction will result in an error.

If you use MySQL or Oracle, which do not support DDL transactions and will only run the `RunPython` operation in a transaction, you can safely put all operations in the same migration. However, you will lose out on some cross-database compatibility.

Comment: That's exactly the sort of transaction/database level interaction I was worried about. Too bad Django doesn't support some sort of "run each operation sequentially, even if you could combine them" flag. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: I'm working with MySQL and either the `RemoveField` or the data migration fails with complaining that the old field does not exist. So there's some shenanigan going on there, the orders got flipped.